# Copy any selected with mouse page text if button is pressed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, copy

Ok, this is all I want to do: say that in my page I select some text and if I press a button, that selected text will be copied (don't know exactly, like ctrl+c, in pc memory) so that I could use that text anywhere later.
Any ideas?

```
enter code here
<input type="button" NAME="cpyButton" value="Copy" onClick="ctrl_c()">

<script type="text/javascript"> 
...
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)